# Bonds in R-H3N+ group

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, amino-acids

[image]
Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwitterion#/media/File:Amino_Acid_Zwitterion_Structural_Formulae_V.1.svg)

I am confused about the ammonium group in this molecule.

I can see that we have a nitrogen atom and 3 hydrogens. The group is attached to a carbon.

Nitrogen has atomic number 7 so my understanding is it can form up to 3 covalent bonds, and therefore cannot have covalent bonds with the carbon and all 3 hydrogens.

I can see a + on the nitrogen, suggesting it is an ion, and maybe some ionic bond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitrogen along with it's 3 bonds has a lone pair. That's what comes into play. The H+ ion has no electrons of it's own and therefore when it forms bond with N, nitrogen coordinates it's lone pair to H+ completing it's duplet and at the same time it's octet and forms a coordinate bond also known as dative-bond.

You can find more about coordinate bond [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_covalent_bond)

Comment: What do you mean with 'pure orbital'?

Comment: Pure orbital means that the pone pair doesn't resides in any of the sp3 hybridized orbitals instead the lone pair is in the pure p-orbital.

Comment: If you mean that you should probably also write pure p orbital. In this case, however, it would not be correct. An amino group has a pyramidal structure, so the resulting lone pair orbital is not pure p; this would require a planar coordination around nitrogen.

Comment: Does that means that lone pair goes in an hybridized orbital ?

Comment: Yes, in the hybridisation description it does.